# Convert JSON to csv - unterminated string. Expected delimiter: "

Tags: json, csv

I've scraped about 3800 iphone ads from this site dba.dk with import.io's web crawler.

Extracting the data from import.io was a bit of a hazzle but using the method described [here](http://support.import.io/forums/238171-support-forum/suggestions/6643306-i-have-crawled-a-site-but-when-i-try-and-view-the) on the support forum,  I was able to download a json file containing my data.

Now i'm trying to convert the json to csv but after trying a bunch of online and offline converters I keep gettting the message:

> unterminated string. Expected delimiter: “.

My knowledge of json is very limited to say the least but I believe I have narrowed it down to be a problem regarding the  json format i.e. the json might be incomplete.

The json can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5djvukyyia77km6/DBA_iphones.json?dl=0). Can any of you clever folks confirm that I have an incomplete json? And what can I do to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON ends in `["dbatracker=\"id=058ee7b3-fc10-42f3-af87-9cfe1cba4caf\";Path=\"/\";Domain=\"www.dba.dk\";Port=\"80\"","dbasession=\"id="` and it's missing ending `]` looking only to this part of string. There might be other errors. Also, you can replace all `\"` with `'` to make some more readable text. Also you can try something like Chrome Postman to do request and get formatted JSON.